# Android - How do I make buttons clickable when new layouts loads

Tags: android, layout, android-intent

I'm trying to make buttons clickable when the new layouts loads...
As what happens... I'm on the layout 1 and i have a few buttons shown...
When I press a button it will straight away show me a new layout with buttons from another .xml.
But it won't let me click anything on layout 2.
How do i make it happen?
My code is below to go from layout 1 to layout R.layout.fail.

```
    Button SectiontwoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Sectiontwo);
    SectiontwoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        private Uri Uri;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.fail);

            Uri uri=Uri;
            Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            mSoundManager.playSound(1);
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Wahid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put both your layouts as child of a viewflipper.

And instead calling setContentView again, you can use

```
viewflipper.setDisplayChild(0);
```

This is the cleaner way of switching between layouts. This should also solve your click problem.

Comment: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-viewflipper-example. Thats a simple tutorial

Comment: Is there another sample. Because I've tried that sample it's a bit confusing only because im dealing with images not TextView.

Comment: you replace textviews with imageviews. There are lots of tutorials if you just google them. or put the 2 xml files up to see what you are trying to switch.